# AppStore &a Google store time to review and approve app update

Tags: android, ios, google-play-services, appstore-approval

How long does it take Apple to review and approve minor app update on AppStore? Also if you have any idea for the same on google play?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about appstore approval times, which will change constantly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

You can check approximate review times for AppStore here : http://appreviewtimes.com/. Bear in mind that this is a rough approximate as reported by users - this is not official Apple data. So although is says `1 day` at the moment of writing l, your review could very well take longer than this.

The extent of the update doesn't matter - you could have changed one label or redesigned your whole app - the review done is the same. You can also request an expedited review if this is a fix for a critical issue. You can read more about expedited reviews here : https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/

As to the Play Store - there is no review proccess. Your update should be available to users after a few hours (from personal experience).

Comment: They did add a review process a while back, but it still seems to go live within a few hours.  I think the official line is within 24 hours.

Comment: Google's policy seems to have changed in recent times.. I've submitted updates to a few apps over the last couple of months and although the console showed the status as published, it only appears in the store almost 24 hours later. Contacted live support and got a canned reply about a "manual review that can take up to 48 hours to complete".